# Using an action filter to get the results of an object and it's action Name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, filter

What i'm looking is for a way to use an action filters that can log info about an method/action that is called from another action. Is this possible?

I'm going to give an example i'm trying to make it work:

I have an action with the name `Create` from the `CampaignsController` that gets posted and inside that action i call another "action/method" that i want to get info logged.

Wha't i've found so far:

Action filter only work on classes that extend `Controller`.

I can't use filters on action/method that get called inside another action.

I can put information inside TempData and after that access it inside the action filter, but i don't know if this is the best solution.

Thanks.

The code i'm using is below:

`CampaingsController`

```
namespace GBD_01.Controllers
{
    [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
    public class CampaignsController : Controller
    {
        private GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.FieldsController controller = new GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.FieldsController();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(string returnUrl = "")
        {
            ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Campaign model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (model.Type == "EMAIL")
            {
                ModelState.Remove("message");
            }
            else if(model.Type == "SMS")
            {
                ModelState.Remove("URL");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                EgoiClass egoiCls = new EgoiClass();
                if (model.Type == "EMAIL")
                {
                   egoiCls.createCampaignEmail(model.CampaignName, model.Subject, model.URL);
                }
                else if (model.Type == "SMS")
                    egoiCls.createCampaignSMS(model.CampaignName, model.Subject, model.message, model.URL);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

method of the object that is called:

```
namespace GBD_01.Controllers
{
    public class EgoiController
    {
    public Dictionary<string, object> createCampaignEmail(string subject, string internal_Name, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            string apikey = vars.getKeyValue("EgoiApiKey");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(apikey))
            {
                GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.FieldsController fieldCtrl = new GBD.FrontOffice.Controllers.FieldsController();
                EgoiApi api = EgoiApiFactory.getApi(Protocol.XmlRpc);
                EgoiMap map = new EgoiMap();
                EgoiMap mapResult = new EgoiMap();
                string senderCode = vars.getKeyValue("EgoiSender");/*ProjectSession.EgoiSenderCode*/; 
                map.Add("apikey", apikey);
                map.Add("from", senderCode);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
                    map.Add("subject", subject);
                /* OPTIONS FOR LINKS IN NEWSLETTERS*/
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vars.getKeyValue("EgoiLinks")))
                {
                    string[] links = vars.getKeyValue("EgoiLinks").Split(';');
                    foreach (string s in links)
                    {
                        map.Add(s, "1");
                    }
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(internal_Name))
                    map.Add("internal_name", internal_Name);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                    map.Add("url", url);
                map.Add("listID", vars.getKeyValue("EgoiContactListId"));
                mapResult = api.createCampaignEmail(map);
                Dictionary<string, object> item = (Dictionary<string, object>)mapResult;
                if (!item.ContainsKey("ERROR"))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

What i mean about action filter is something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class LogActionResult : ActionFilterAttribute //TESTE - os action filter apenas funcion em controladores e acções
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogActionResult).Name);

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        ActionExecutedContext context = filterContext;
        StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder();
        Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        Log("OnResultExecuting ", filterContext.RouteData);
    }

    private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
    {
        var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
        var message = String.Format("{0}- controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName,
                                                                    controllerName,
                                                                    actionName);
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

I want to use there is a log package to save information about what happened and information about the api call:

```
                log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("LoginLog");
                logger.Info("Acção: action name | result: '"+mapResult+"' | logged at " + DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: That question is way too long. Please shorten your question to the absolute minimum, the core information that we can understand and rebuild your problem. No one really wants to read through such a huge question, it discourages people, especially because everbody knows that this question can be asked shorter. So shorten it and people are more likely to help you.

Comment: I've reorganized the question. I think it's easier to read now. I've kept the code blocks because i think it's important.

Comment: But thats still too much, no one will go through all this. Remove all the unnecessary parts.

Comment: Hope the question is direct to the point now. thanks for pointing that.